# Marshmallow: Deserializing for nested fields using load({}).data

Tags: python, marshmallow

I see this scenario has been asked before, so apologies in advance for this duplicate case.
I'm trying to deserialize a schema that has nested fields. Here's an example:

```
class _SpeedSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    level = fields.Integer(missing=10)

class ParentSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    id = fields.String(missing='fake_id')
    datetime = fields.Integer(missing=int(common.get_current_utc_time()))
    speed = fields.Nested(_SpeedSchema, many=True)
```

Next, I proceed with Python console to load from ParentSchema like so
`ParentSchema().load({}).data`. As a result, I'm getting the following output

```
{'id': 'fake_id', 'datetime': 1580482336929}
```

I was expecting nested field: **speed** to be included in this output, since it has **level** with a value of **10** already assigned. So the output should be like this:

```
{'id': 'fake_id', 'datetime': 1580482336929, 'speed': {'level': 10}}
```

How do we include the nested field in this output? Any help with example code would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently you're using marshmallow 2. I thought your use case would work with marshmallow 2 but not marshmallow 3. In any case, this might be a useful read: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1042.

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme, this helps out.